# How to limit the number of items that can be selected in *2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I'm trying to limit to a certain numbers of records that can be selected in a *2many field. This limit is defined by another field.

I've defined the field that I want to limit like this:

```
max = fields.Integer('Max partners')
partner_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.partner', relation='my_model_partners', column1='mymodel_id', column2="partner_id")
```

First I tried this:

```
<field name="partner_ids" options="{'limit': max}" widget="many2many"/>
```

But I can select more than `max` partners and nothing happens. And second I try to define a `constraint` to limit the number of `partner_ids`:

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('partner_ids')
def _check_limit(self):
    if len(self.partner_ids)>=self.max:
        raise ValidationError("Max number of partners")
```

This works but it raise the error only when I save the record but what I want is to limit the number of records that can be selected, so I can't select more than `max` record for the `partner_ids`field.

Comment: try @api.onchange('partner_ids') in parallel with @api.constrains('partner_ids')

Comment: Ok thanks, with `onchange` and `constrains` together I can do what I want

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly this but I don't know how to remove the items or prevent them from being added. Could you please share your solution? Thank you!